# First RavenDB 2.0 Backup: Could not load file or assembly Raven.Abstractions

Tags: ravendb

I'm running my RavenDB backup batch file for the first time since upgrading to RavenDB 2.0.

**This is the command:**

> C:>"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\RavenDB\RavenDB-Build-2230\Backup\Raven.Backup.exe" --url
>   `http://localhost:8080` --dest="c:\temp\RavenBackup"

**And this is the error:**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Raven.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I checked RavenDB.net, and the backup procedure looks to be the same as before for RavenDB 2.0. What am I missing? I could start moving assemblies within the RavenDB folder structure, but I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the Raven.Abstractions.dll next to the Raven.Backup.exe file.

Comment: Will this be added to the documentation?